# Is it possible to load non-default launchd plist files from the /etc configuration file?

Tags: launchd

I created the /etc/launchd.conf file but at start the content is never read.

The content of launchd.conf is: load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/KillVuze.plist

(I run on OSX 10.7.2 )

If I load the plist by command line the "launchd list" show my plist as registered, but not after reboot even if I proper set the /etc/launchd.conf

Is this loading of non-default plist files (those stored outside the normal locations) best accomplished in this manner?

Comment: Is there some reason you need to save the plist in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/`? Ones in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` and `/Library/LaunchAgents/` should get loaded automatically.

Answer (score 3):

To load a [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html) job at start up, you need to store your [job description plist file](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) in one of two folders:

- `/Library/LaunchAgents`
- `/Library/LaunchDaemons`

Do not edit or store launchd job description files in the `/System` folder. This folder is reserved for exclusive use by Apple.

You do not need to edit any configuration files.